# How do I use this FFMPEG command in python script?

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg

**I am trying to extract a single frame at every second from a video** , Using this command on command line using ffmpeg **ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -r 1 %04d.jpg**

I am able to do this task using ffmpeg on command line.

But I want to use same command in python script, how do I do that and what should be the code?
I am very new to this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could you `os.system` or you could use the [ffmpeg library](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/), but since it is only *one* command I would just use the `os.system` method

```
# importing os module  
import os  

input_file = 'something.mp4' # You should enter the file's path here
# Using fstring for variable file name
# Command to execute 
# Using Windows OS command 
cmd = f'ffmpeg -i {input_file} -r 1 %04d.jpg'
# Using os.system() method 
os.system(cmd)
```